# Plotting Co-ordinates with MKMapView using Polyline (Swift)

Tags: swift, mkmapview, coordinates, polyline

I am trying to use MKMapView to plot pre-determined coordinates on a map. The following code is triggered by a button.

The array 'coordinatesArr' is 2D, and contains latitude, longitude, and a timestamp. Each element is stored as a string for other reasons, and therefore co-ordinates are converted to Doubles when loaded.

Example:

```
 [["37.33027293", "-122.02788965", "2018-05-30 15:18:21.459808+0100"], ["37.33026014", "-122.02768476", "2018-05-30 15:18:22.459808+0100"]]
```

The code is held within the following class:

```
 class PostCell: UITableViewCell, MKMapViewDelegate
```

**Code**

```
 (MAP IS THE FOLLOWING OUTLET: @IBOutlet weak var activityFeedMap: MKMapView!)

 let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.001, 0.001)
 // ALTHOUGH THIS WILL NOT BE MY ULTIMATE METHOD, THE MAP IS CURRENTLY CENTRED ON THE FIRST LOCATION
 let myLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Double(coordinatesArr[0][1]) ?? 0.0, Double(coordinatesArr[0][0])!)
 let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
 activityFeedMap.setRegion(region, animated:true)
 activityFeedMap.delegate=self
 activityFeedMap.mapType = MKMapType.hybrid

 // CODE IN QUESTION
 // ---
 // PERHAPS I SHOULD LOOP THROUGH THE ARRAY, BUT I BELIEVE THIS
 // FULFILS THE SAME PURPOSE
 var counter=0
 while counter < (coordinatesArr.count - 1){

    // LASTLOCFORMATTED, AND NEXTLOCFORMATTED ARE EACH A SET OF
    // CO-ORDINATES BETWEEN WHICH A POLYLINE SHOULD BE PLOTTED
    let lastLocFormatted = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Double(coordinatesArr[counter][1])!, Double(coordinatesArr[counter][0])!)

    let nextLocFormatted = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Double(coordinatesArr[counter+1][1])!, Double(coordinatesArr[counter+1][0])!)

    // AN ARRAY HOLDING THE CO-ORDINATES OF THE POINTS TO PLOT
    // A POLYLINE BETWEEN
    var a=[lastLocFormatted, nextLocFormatted]

    // LINE TO PLOT
    let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &a, count: counter)

    activityFeedMap.add(polyline)

    COUNTER += 1
 }


func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    // CHECK TO SEE WHETHER OVERLAY IS OF TYPE MKPOLYLINE
    // AND ONLY LAY TRACE IF TIMER RUNNING
    // note: different renderer required for differnt types
    if overlay is MKPolyline{
        // CREATE MKPOLYLINERENDERER AND PASS OUR OVERLAY OVER
        let polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        // SET LINE COLOR TO BLUE
        polylineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.orange
        // SET LINE WIDTH TO 4
        polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 4
        return polylineRenderer
    }
    // IF OVERLAY NOT OF TYPE MKPOLYLINE
    return MKPolylineRenderer()
}
```

Although this code is partly working, I am gaining extra data somehow.

```
 37.33027293, -122.02788965
 37.33026634, -122.0278357
 37.33026525, -122.02778504
 37.33026222, -122.02773507
 37.33026014, -122.02768476
```

The above should plot:

[image]

This code creates the following, however

[image]

The line outlined in blue appears to continue on indefinitely.

Any help that you can provide would be greatly appreciated, as I am new to Swift and have exhausted all rectifying actions I can think of.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'd recommend using https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkpolyline/1452773-polylinewithpoints  poloylineWithPoints instead
of adding a polyline for each one.

What it looks like is your overshooting and your last segment is zooming off to Zero Island.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Although I didn't manage to fix my original code, by implementing your suggestions I was able to get it working.